# Qt6 cannot find header files

Tags: qt, qt6

A problem happened in my project which has just been created in Qt6,the compiler can't find header files(such as `QMainWindow`)
When I try to use qmake,it shows:

```
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/awa23/Desktop/计算机/Programme/Qt/build-Qt6Test-Desktop_Qt_6_3_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'
C:\Qt\6.3.1\mingw_64\bin\rcc.exe -name qmake_qmake_qm_files debug\qmake_qmake_qm_files.qrc -o debug\qrc_qmake_qmake_qm_files.cpp
C:\Qt\6.3.1\mingw_64\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN --include C:/Users/awa23/Desktop/璁＄畻鏈Programme/Qt/build-Qt6Test-Desktop_Qt_6_3_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/debug/moc_predefs.h -IC:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/mkspecs/win32-g++ -IC:/Users/awa23/Desktop/璁＄畻鏈Programme/Qt/Qt6Test -IC:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/include -IC:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/include/QtCore -I. -IC:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++ -IC:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -IC:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include/c++/backward -IC:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include -IC:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/include-fixed -IC:/Qt/Tools/mingw1120_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include ..\Qt6Test\mainwindow.h -o debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp
RCC Parse Error: 'debug\qmake_qmake_qm_files.qrc' Line: 1 Column: 2 [Encountered incorrectly encoded content.]
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Debug:113: debug/qrc_qmake_qmake_qm_files.cpp] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Warning: Failed to resolve include "C:/Users/awa23/Desktop/鐠侊紕鐣婚張?Programme/Qt/build-Qt6Test-Desktop_Qt_6_3_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/debug/moc_predefs.h" for moc file ..\Qt6Test\mainwindow.h
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/awa23/Desktop/计算机/Programme/Qt/build-Qt6Test-Desktop_Qt_6_3_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:45: debug] Error 2
00:01:07: 进程"C:\Qt\Tools\mingw1120_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe"退出，退出代码 2 。
Error while building/deploying project Qt6Test (kit: Desktop Qt 6.3.1 MinGW 64-bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

The problem occurs not only in my project,but also in Qt libraries.As you can see,even if QtCreator can find that header file,but when I try to build it,it can't find header files,it can't even find C++ standard libraries.It cannot find any header files,completely.It can only find header files when I include a absolute path.
Operating System: Windows11
The version of Qt: 6.3.1
Errors shown in Qt Creator:

[image: Error]
[image: E1]
[image: E2]

Comment: did you add `QT += widgets` in `.pro` file ? and also you need `QT += core gui`

Comment: your compiler didn't find `QMainWindow` class. it will add libraries when you tell it from your `.pro` file because of that you need to add `QT += widgets`. If you checked it and there was it in the `.pro` file then it means that you didn't install `Qt` modules. in your Drive which installs Qt must be lots of `dlls` for each module, you want to use.

Comment: For future reference: This path (`C:/Users/awa23/Desktop/鐠侊紕鐣婚張?Programme`) does not look right, it might be `C:/Users/awa23/Desktop/鐠侊紕鐣婚張/Programme` or something like that. the non English characters in paths seem to be causing this, or at least some of it. Using a path that does not contain them might help.

Answer (score -1):

This will happen if you didn't install `QT` correctly.

**you should install Qt and be sure that you checked important modules**

[image]

[image]

**If you just install Qt compilers and Qt creator you will get that error.**

go to  `MaintenanceTool` and **select add and remove** and add checked Qt modules.

Then be sure that your `.pro` File has these items:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: i did so but it still can't work

Comment: @Java_Herobrine so I don't know, you should explain more in question.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details added.